# Tell if a C# method runs

Tags: c#

Is it possible, somehow, to trace if a C# method has been run by adding some code in it? **I do not want to be in debug mode**, so something like `Trace.WriteLine` is not acceptable. I just want to run my project normally and tell if some methods have been called or not. I am new to C# and I have a Javascript background, so what actually I want is something similar to `console.log()`.

Comment: Methods are yours ?

Comment: Write something to a file...

Comment: Someone should invent a logging framework... oh they have

Comment: Use `Console.WriteLine` or (it would be better) use logging framework, `log4net` for example

Comment: File.AppendAllText("C:\\log.txt", "i has been logged");

Comment: If you are looking for something similar to console.log, just use a C# logger and log into a text file whatever methods are running. If you don't want to log it and just want to know for the current instance then it's better to use a boolean flag and set it to true when the method is executed and from the flag value you will know.

Comment: Better to give more information like, what is your application type and how you want to display status etc...

Comment: Why do you think that `Trace.WriteLine` requires you to be in debug mode?

Answer (score 3):

It depends whether you are talking about a console application, web application or desktop application.

If you are running a console application you can make use of the `System.Console.WriteLine` method and write to the console. This works in debug mode as well as in release mode.

If you are running a web application or desktop application you do not have the possibility to write to the console but you can write to the file system. Most of the time people use dedicated logging frameworks such as [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an event and trigger it when the method is executed.

Declare the class containing the event:

```
class MyClass {
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public void Method() {
        OnEvent();
    }

    private void OnEvent() {
        if (MyEvent != null) {
            MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    void Event_Hander()
    {
        Consol.WriteLine("Executed!");
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.MyEvent += new EventHandler(Event_Handler);
myObject.Method();
```

I would read a bit about events before reading my code.

Comment: Could you provide some code for that?

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper, I added some code, I did not try it, but it should work